# Is it good practice to call XML from another XML in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am new in Android App development and loving this .

Is it good practice to call XML from another XML? Does this means to save app run time ?

XML 1(activity_main):

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:name="com.loginfbk.MainFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

XML 2(fragment_main):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/messenger_button_white_bg_round"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Depend upon situation. Suppose you have large screen or multiple sections then you can make multiple layout for that. Otherwise no need.

Comment: The `tools:...` namespace only works inside the IDE not on real device. Does that code really work?

Comment: you can do `<include>` tag to reuse the Layouts

Comment: @ElvisChweya this code runs and i was confused at staring .

Comment: @BDudhraj, maybe you also have Java code to hook up the `FragmentTransaction` stuff but you are overlooking that.

Comment: Also, by setting `android:name="com.loginfbk.MainFragment"` you pretty much asked Android to setup all the stuff behind the scenes. So once you setup `MainFragment` you are done. It's not what the `tools:layout..` part

Comment: @ElvisChweya thnx i got it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it good practice to call XML from another XML?

In general case NO, in your case YES.

In General: if you plan to reuse everywhere almost every reusable layout and you do a code refactoring to extract the common parts, that is fine, it will work. The problem it comes later. Later you change your mind to add a little something, or your client has a brilliant idea. You will change it and you will pray to not break the code elsewhere.

Also some IDE are able to show you the included parts, other not!

In some cases you need to include views **dynamically**. Ex. 5 row with a "form and "to" text inputs and after that a "button" holder, and if the user click on something add / remove others, maybe add a text area.
In this nasty cases you don't really have a choice: only included elements, changing on the fly. Fortunately this is not a general case in Android development.

Except the above mentioned case I would reuse components, when I plan to use a components, which looks like the same on tablet, and phone too: like a "Show licenses" button, or for German companies the "Imprint" in other case I would go to write the full xml, because in reality you need to duplicate the code 3-5 times max in the project and you can see what is there instantly and change it instantly, without affecting other layouts, especially if your layout hold more then 1 controller + 1-2 wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Sometimes you want to reuse views. Therefore, instead of duplicating lines of XML multiple times, the best way is to reuse the xml views. That is why we have the `include` tag in android schemas.

```
<include layout="@layout/reusable_view" />
```

In our case, the `reusable_view.xml` could contain any defined view to be injected in the other view.